# How to do padding in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, keras, deep-learning

I have a dataset contain of URLs. and after URLs I have related information. I'm going to use deeplearning algorithm to train and test the model. I have an issue of lenght. Now I want to calculate which has a lot of data and then after that if the data is less than that ammount pad it with 0 instead of url1_data or url2_data. but if the same url come in the middle of two different url drop that url. I have no code to post because I don't know how to do it.

```
col1  col2  col3 
1      2     url1 
1      2     url1_data 
1      2     url1_data 
1      2     url1
1      2     url1_data 
1      2     url1_data 
1      2     url2 
1      2     url2_data 
1      2     url2_data
```

Expected output::

```
col1  col2  col3 
1      2     url1 
1      2     url1_data 
1      2     url1_data 
1      2     url1_data 
1      2     url1_data 
1      2     url2 
1      2     url2_data 
1      2     url2_data
1      2     url2_data(0) # 0 padded 
1      2     url2_data(0) # 0 padded
```

length is equal now and the repeated URL is also removed

and a lot of data mean number of rows related to that url. like for `url1` I have 4 rows `url1_data` which is more data than `url2` data(rows) so I add two extra rows below `url2`. so now the data are same. suppose we have `url3` having three rows which is less than `url1` so I need to add only one `url3_data(0)` mean this is padded value

Comment: Either a reproducible example (_input_) or the expected output is missing in your question. Can you add it ?

Comment: this is the input shape

Comment: @abokey cany you please check it now

Answer (score 1):

I'm not entirely sure what you mean by 'calculate which has a lot of data', but you could try making use of the Python *ljust()* method such as:

```py
col3 = col3.ljust(15, '0')
```

where '15' represents the length of string with the padding, and '0' is the character to pad with.

Comment: a lot of data mean number of rows related to that url. like for `url1` I have more data than `url2` so I add two extra rows below `url2`. so now the data are same. suppose we have `url3` having three rows which is less than `url1` so I need to add only one `url3_data(0)` mean this is padded value